# Query to SQLite returning signed int16 but was defined as unsigned

Tags: c#, sqlite, reflection, casting

I am using SQLite for ADO.NET, the .NET v4.0 binaries to be exact.

I have hit a problem while trying to populate the data of a class based on the contents of an extract from the database.

The reflection code:

```
var type = this.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach(var property in properties)
{
    property.SetValue(this, row[property.Name]);
}
```

However this throws the exception:
 
**Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt16'.**

The value is it trying to populate is a *ushort*.
In the sql to initially generate the table, that column is defined as 'UNSIGNED SMALLINT' which to my understanding should be the same as C# *ushort*.

The creation SQL-

```
CREATE TABLE [Monsters]
                        (
                            [MonsterID]     UNSIGNED SMALLINT   NOT NULL     UNIQUE, 
                            [MonsterName]   VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL, 
                            [ElementMask]   UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [Str]           UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [Dex]           UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [Int]           UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [Con]           UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [Spd]           UNSIGNED TINYINT    NOT NULL, 
                            [ImageSetID]    UNSIGNED SMALLINT   NULL
                        )
```

Removing 'UNSIGNED' throws up this exception instead: 
**Object of type 'System.Int16' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt16'.**
Which is expected given the signed/unsigned mismatch.

Inspecting the row in debug mode shows the expected data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ayts.png

Not quite sure what is going on so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); the column type is ignored, and the type of the returned value depends only on the value itself.

Use the `PropertyType` to convert the value to the correct type.

Comment: Hmm, SQLite is odd. Useful though. Thanks CL.